# How do I list all plugins aviable to webkit?

Tags: javascript, webkit

After a WebKit plugin has been installed [it can be deployed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/Concepts/AboutPlugins.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001248-BAJGJJAH).  How do I obtain a list of all plugins that are currently installed?  I am on Linux, and I know the directory with all of the `.so` plugins that are installed.  However, I don't know know their `CLASSID` values and I don't know of any other way of instantiating them within JavaScript.  Is there a file or directory that I can look in that has these `CLASSID` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside the `navigator.mimeTypes` object. This will not give you `CLASSID` but you can check that plugin for your `mime-type` is available.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EEKW/1/)

Comment: how do I create a new instance of one of these objects?

Comment: I think you should try to create following HTML structure `<object width="100" height="100"><param name="src" value="testfile"></object>` where `testfile` will be backend handler which will respond required `mime-type` so that browser will try to autodetect and use correct plugin for such `<object>`